# Enumerate change to non standard order

Tags: enumerate

I have a enumerated list like this:

U.1 Something 1

U.2 Something 2

U.3 Something 3

U.4 Something 4

U.5 Something 5

And I would like very much to modify the counting as

U.1 Something 1

U.2 Something 2

U.1-2 Something 3 (HERE is the difference.)

U.3 Something 4

U.4 Something 5

etc...

Would anyone have a solution for this?
Thanks

Comment: just use `\item[U.1--2]`

Comment: Yes that is. Thank you it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `\item[U.1--2]` for an item not in the automatic sequence